# PHP add data to array object PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Im trying to add data to each of the array objects below.

```
[
       {
          "first_name":"Chris",
          "surname":"Mowbray",
          "id":"28"
       },
       {
          "first_name":"Gary",
          "surname":"Hume",
          "id":"29"
       },
       {
          "first_name":"Ian",
          "surname":"Hume",
          "id":"30"
       }
    ]
```

this is the php that generates the array shown:

```
<?php
$selectedMatch = '( select max(event.match_id) from event)';
// need to update this match id based on usered slected on site
$getMatchPlayers = "select first_name,surname, id\n" . "from player, match_player\n" . "where player.id = match_player.player_id\n" . "and match_player.match_id = $selectedMatch";
$result = mysql_query($getMatchPlayers) or die(mysql_error());
$temp = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $temp[]    = $row;
    $player_id = $row['id'];
    $AppResult = mysql_query(getApps($player_id)) or die(mysql_error());
    $appearence = mysql_fetch_assoc($AppResult);
    // fb($temp);
}



header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($temp);
exit;
function getApps($playerid){
    $getAppearances = "SELECT COUNT(player_id) \n" . "AS Appearances \n" . "FROM match_player\n" . "where player_id = $playerid\n";
    return $getAppearances;
}
?>
```

im trying to add new data after 'id' of every object but everything that I have tried has added a new index to the array.

$appearence is what i want to add

Comment: Are you sure that this is an [ArrayObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) and not simply an associative [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)?

Comment: I think it is an associative array, im quite new to PHP

Comment: @MarkBaker... forgot to tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$row['appearance']=$appearance['Appearance'] and assign $temp[]=$row as the last statement in the while()

Comment: Note that you can write a query which returns all the lines you want, with all the data you need in one step (the DBMS is faster than PHP, and SQL query turnaround is time-consuming).

Comment: $temp[]    = $row; needs to be at the top as i need the data in order to return  $AppResult see.

Comment: Yes, you should do what Lewyx said and return all your data in one query.

Comment: @clhereistian i dont think that is possible in my instance

Comment: @ChrisMowbray: sorry, I think you're wrong on both instances, but feel free to elaborate your point! The query would be something like this: `select first_name,surname,id, (SELECT COUNT(player_id) AS Apperances FROM match_player mp WHERE mp.player_id=match_player.player_id) from player INNER JOIN match_player ON player.id = match_player.player_id WHERE match_player.match_id = ?` If you DBMS does not allow that kind of parameter access in subselects, then you have a bit harder job to do (INNER JOIN on an aggregate subquery) but it will still be lighting fast compared to your approach.

Comment: something like this would do it:

select 
 first_name, 
 surname,
 (select count(*) from match_player m where m.player_id = player.id) appearances
from player
inner join match_player on player.id = match_player.player_id 
where 
 match_player.match_id = $selectedMatch

Comment: Haha. My comment is almost exactly like @Lewyx.

Comment: @Lewyx wow thanks alot ii didnt know this was possible. this is combining 2 querys. is it possible to combine say 9 queries? also my table is relational, do i still need the INNER JOIN?

Thanks again

Comment: Sure, that is called a subquery. I wouldn't go hog wild with them, but in this case, it seems like a good idea.

Comment: @clhereistian  okay great, could you show me how to add this: SELECT COUNT(player_id) 
AS Trys  
FROM event
where player_id = 42
AND event = 'Try Scored'
AND match_id = 6

and i think i will be able to add the other 6 from here. thanks guys

Comment: `FROM A INNER JOIN B ON X` is the same as `FROM A,B WHERE X` but it is easier to read because you don't mess up your WHERE filtering conditions with the conditions needed to join the tables. You can join any number of tables/views/queries as resources permit, and typically you should (to run as few queries as possible).

Comment: If you are going to do counts by each event.event types, then you pursue something that SQL does in a single command (and in a single sweep of a table), it is called PIVOT table: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78

Comment: @Lewyx this is the only COUNT i need to do. so could you show me the example of the 3 together?

Comment: `select first_name,surname,id, (SELECT COUNT(player_id) AS Apperances FROM match_player mp WHERE mp.player_id=match_player.player_id), (SELECT COUNT(player_id) AS Tries FROM match_player mp2 WHERE mp2.player=match_player.player_id AND event='Try Scored' AND match_id=?) from player INNER JOIN match_player ON player.id = match_player.player_id WHERE match_player.match_id = ?` - but this is now many sweeps of the table which is still faster than PHP but could be made less verbose, and more efficient. Also note that not only COUNT but any aggregate function can be used for the one sweep.

Comment: Let's say you also have a column `points` that shows points gained, and an `event_date` for to store the time/date of every event. You can use

`SELECT * FROM player INNER JOIN (
 SELECT
  player_id AS id,
  SUM(IF(event='Try scored',1,0)) AS Tries,
  SUM(IF(event='Cancelled',1,0)) AS Cancellations,
  COUNT(event) AS EventCount,
  COUNT(DISTINCT event) AS EventTypeCount,
  SUM(points) AS PointScored,
  MAX(event_date) AS LastEventDate
 FROM match_player
 WHERE match_id=?
) stats ON stats.id=player.id˙

Comment: Notice that there is no need for the outter use of the match_player table, and that this solution scans both tables only once. (The previous solution with the subselect scans the match_player table twice FOR EVERY player.)
Also note that all previous versions (including your question) do not filter Apperances to the selected match_id (do you really want to count all events for all match_ids for the player, or did you just forget an " AND match_id=?" part?

Comment: this has been a great help!!, and yea i sort of want both i.e show match stats for all players for 'current match' and also a another query to show all stats for players this season i.e total of all stats

Comment: @Lewyx also i am doing various counts. your first way seemed easier to me so i have this.. http://s1.postimg.org/tmusl2rbz/peoplw.png

Comment: It's all manageable and faster with the last query (your version will get performance troubles as the number of players rises). The latest query would read `SELECT * FROM player INNER JOIN ( SELECT player_id AS id, COUNT(player_id) as Appearances, SUM(IF(event=+Try scored",1,0)) AS Trys, SUM(IF(event="Drop Goal",1,0)) AS Kicks, SUM(IF(event="Tackle",1,0) AS Tackles ... FROM match_player WHERE match_id=? ) stats ON stats.id=player.id˙ - this counts only the selected match_ids (you can scrap that WHERE). The picture you sent uses the data of all matches for the stats.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
 $temp['newKey'] = $appearence;
```

Comment: Try adding your new value to $row before you add $row to $temp.

Comment: i cannot do that as the new value is found using data in row... $player_id = $row['id'] and then player_id is used in the sql to return the new data $appearance

Comment: $row is a simple array, you can read AND write its elements in any order you wish; just don't assign to the whole array, because that will replace the whole.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a [merged](http://php.net/array_merge) array containing both results **after** you've retrieved all required information.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $player_id  = $row['id'];
    $AppResult  = mysql_query(getApps($player_id)) or die(mysql_error());
    $appearence = mysql_fetch_assoc($AppResult);
    $temp[]     = array_merge($row, $appearance);
}
```

Be careful not to have the same array key in `$row` and `$appearance` when doing this, presume you won't have a problem.